# Other uses of Class Extension in objective-c besides the known one

Tags: objective-c

I am currently using class extension in all my Objective-c projects.

I suppose it's just a question of 'language', but by reading the Apple documentation at this link [Categories and Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1):

> A common use for class extensions is to redeclare property that is
> publicly declared as read-only privately as readwrite:
> ......
>
> It
> is also generally common for a class to have a publicly declared API
> and to then have additional methods declared privately for use solely
> by the class or the framework within which the class resides.

Actually, when in my mother tongue when we say 'common', it means an implicit way of saying "there's also something else...".

So my very basic question is ? Are there any other scenarios where extension could be used.

Comment: Just to clarify, extensions as in categories right?

Comment: yes, I added a link to Apple doc

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer Extensions are similar to categories, but not identical (they do not have a name and the implementation of any method must be done in the main implementation of the class).

Comment: @Leonardo according to OsX dictionary 'common' means _occurring, found, or done often; prevalent_ so there need not be any intrinsic "there's also something else". But of course apple already gives two different uses, so for each of them "there's also something else" does apply (at a minimum there's also the other case :P ).

Comment: Yes, I supposed it was a question of language. That's infact the case, I know it may sound curious but when we say 'done often', we knows there's something which is 'done less', but at least it exists. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: let my clarify it again you "just" want information about class extensions an not categories which extend classes?

Answer (score 1):

One typical additional use of class extensions which is defined as:

```
@interface SomeClass()
@end
```

is to declare private methods used by the class implementation.  As of Xcode 4.4 (I think), it is no longer necessary to declare private methods before they are defined in the implementation - so I rarely use class extensions now.

**EDIT**:

oops, sorry, I didn't pay attention to the second paragraph in the OP's original quote. Well, that's the only uses, I can think of, then.

Comment: A good link for your answer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html

Comment: Except that it is not an 'additional' use. It's is part of the second use-case given by Apple documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A class extension also let you add iVars to a class.

This way, you can *hide* iVars from your public header files.

I know a lot of people simply uses synthesised properties for everything, especially with ARC.
I won't discuss this, as it's not the topic, but it is actually two completely different things, as a property is at least readable from the outside.

So with a class extension, you can have your private iVars hidden and safe.
This helps keeping your public headers clean, and it also prevent child classes to acces them, whenever it's needed.

**Edit**

As stated by Pfitz in the comments, this can now also be done, with modern runtimes, directly in an implementation:

```
@implementation
{
   ... // iVars
}
```

Comment: With modern runtimes you do not need them anymore for private iVars - just use: `@implementation Myclass { NSObject *myObject}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a class extension to declare protocol conformance without advertising it to the world.

Comment: Nice one. Note this is also true with categories.